# iphone zoom to user location on mapkit

Tags: iphone, mapkit, zooming

I'm using map kit and showing user's location using "showsUserLocation"
I"m using following code to zoom to user's location, but not zooming. Its zooming to some location in Africa, though the user location on map is showing correct.

```
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion; 
MKUserLocation* usrLocation = mapView.userLocation; 
newRegion.center.latitude = usrLocation.location.coordinate.latitude; 
newRegion.center.longitude = usrLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 20.0;
newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 28.0; 
[self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
```

Why is user's location correctly showing and not zooming properly. Can some one correct me please?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

mapView.userLocation is set to a location off the coast of Africa (0,0) when first instantiated. As a result, I do something like the following, which causes the zoom to occur when the annotation appears. Of course, this is just an example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
        if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation) {
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;

            span.latitudeDelta=0.1;
            span.longitudeDelta=0.1; 

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mv.userLocation.coordinate;

            region.span=span;
            region.center=location;

            [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
            [mv regionThatFits:region];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
mapView.userTrackingMode=YES;
mapView.userTrackingMode=NO;
```

UserTrackingMode will zoom to user Location.

Comment: This goes to current location, but does not zoom gracefully.

Comment: In iOs 8.3 it zooms gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the location returned by `mapView.userLocation` isn't at 0, 0?

Comment: If the user location is zero, it wouldn't have shown the annotation pin exactly that matches my location.

Comment: @satyam: with lat/lon delta as you described it, you would be able to include Africa in the zoom since 0,0 is not that far off the coast. Besides, you didn't tell where the user location is.